# What needs to be done to download a maven dependency in virtual desktop environment?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, vdi

I am not able to download the maven dependencies in a Virtual desktop environment. Even though I have set up the server details in my settings.xml file just keep on getting the following error.
Error Msg: Could not resolve dependencies for project "sample project": Failed to collect dependencies at

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Maybe share your pom.xml and/or settings.xml. Is the virtual desktop connected to the internet? Is the repository available via ping...

Comment: Hi, @DrHopfen thanks for the response. Actually, the most accurate message that I am getting if I run mvn clean install -X is as follows: PKIX path building failed: 

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find the valid certification path to the requested target.  

Checked for a proxy there isn't one. Other information Java we use is 11.

Comment: Seems like need to export a certificate for the client not sure if users will work or if it needs to be admins. Please guide.